# Cannot see Get Snapshot button in JetBrains/DotTrace Profiler Controller, after clicking detach in previous session?

Tags: dottrace

I am using DotTrace 2018.3 from JetBrains Ultimate.

I am trying to profile a ASP.NET 4.7 MVC 5 web application from within VS2017.

I have noticed that sometimes when I start a profile session ie via :

Resharper > Profile > Run StartUp Configuration Performance Profiling

The Profiling Controller starts up, but without the "Detach" or "Kill" buttons and also without the "Get Snapshort and Wait" button.

How can I resolve this please?

I have also noticed that I have caused this in the past by clicking on "Detach", but thereafter the Profiler Controller seems to fail to pick up any process.

I have just restarted VS2017 and closed down IIS Express, and gone back into VS2017 and restarted my "Sampling" Profile session and this time I am seeing the relevant buttons....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you need to warm up your web app by sending a request to it right after the start of profiling. The buttons will be available in profiling controller right after that.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will test this advice.